# Gridview ListView

Tags: php, listview, gridview

I need to have this page toggle between grid and list view and for the life of me cannot get it to work. The page should not refresh and behave as craigslist page do

Here is my code:

```
 <?php include('t_msg.html');


    <?php 

    defined('_JEXEC') OR defined('_VALID_MOS') OR die( "Direct Access Is Not Allowed" );?>


    <?php
    //echo "<br><br><br>User: ";

    $jAp= & JFactory::getApplication();
    $user =& JFactory::getUser();
    $usr_id = $user->get('id');
    $usr_name = $user->get('name');
    $email_id = $user->get('email');
    //echo " User: $usr_id";
    //echo " User: $email_id";

    ?>


    <html>
    <head>
    <!-- Javascript goes in the document HEAD -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function altRows(id){
        if(document.getElementsByTagName){  

            var table = document.getElementById(id);  
            var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

            for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){          
                if(i % 2 == 0){
                    rows[i].className = "evenrowcolor";
                }else{
                    rows[i].className = "oddrowcolor";
                }      
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload=function(){
        altRows('alternatecolor');
    }
    </script>

    <!-- CSS goes in the document HEAD or added to your external stylesheet -->
    <style type="text/css">
    .CSSTableGenerator {
        margin:0px;padding:0px;
        width:100%;
        box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
        border:1px solid #000000;

        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:0px;

        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:0px;

        -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
        border-top-right-radius:0px;

        -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
        border-top-left-radius:0px;
    }.CSSTableGenerator table{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0px;padding:0px;
    }.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child {
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    }
    .CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:first-child {
        -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
        border-top-left-radius:0px;
    }

    .CSSTableGenerator table th {
        background:#0057af url('cell-blue.jpg');
        border-width: 1px;
        padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #999999;
    font-size:10px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:normal;
        color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    .CSSTableGenerator table tr:first-child td:last-child {
        -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
        border-top-right-radius:0px;
    }.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:first-child{
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    }.CSSTableGenerator tr:hover td{

    }
    .CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(odd){ background-color:#aad4ff; }
    .CSSTableGenerator tr:nth-child(even)    { background-color:#ffffff; }.CSSTableGenerator td{
        vertical-align:middle;


        border:1px solid #000000;
        border-width:0px 1px 1px 0px;
        text-align:left;
        padding:7px;
        font-size:10px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:normal;
        color:#000000;
    }.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td{
        border-width:0px 1px 0px 0px;
    }.CSSTableGenerator tr td:last-child{
        border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
    }.CSSTableGenerator tr:last-child td:last-child{
        border-width:0px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
    .CSSTableGenerator th:first-child td{
            background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #005fbf 5%, #003f7f 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #005fbf), color-stop(1, #003f7f) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #005fbf 5%, #003f7f 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#005fbf", endColorstr="#003f7f");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#005fbf,003f7f);

        background-color:#005fbf;
        border:0px solid #000000;
        text-align:center;
        border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
        font-size:14px;
        font-family:Arial;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#ffffff;
    }
    .CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child:hover td{
        background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, #005fbf 5%, #003f7f 100%);    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #005fbf), color-stop(1, #003f7f) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #005fbf 5%, #003f7f 100% );
        filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr="#005fbf", endColorstr="#003f7f");  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,#005fbf,003f7f);

        background-color:#005fbf;
    }
    .CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:first-child{
        border-width:0px 0px 1px 0px;
    }
    .CSSTableGenerator tr:first-child td:last-child{
        border-width:0px 0px 1px 1px;
    }
    </style>

    </head>
    <div class="products_look">
        <input type="button" class="view_list" onclick="location.reload() = '/index.php?option=com_aclsfgpl&md=check2'" value="List" />
        <input type="button" class="view_grid" onclick="location.reload() = '/ndex.php?option=com_aclsfgpl&md=check3'" value="Grid" />



    <div class="CSSTableGenerator" >
    <table border="2"  class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
        <tr>

            <th>Value</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Zipcode</th>
            <th>Item #</th>
                 <th>Image</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>

    </html>
    <?php
    $r = NULL;
    $z = NULL;
    $stores = NULL;
    $Errors = NULL;

    function Dist ($lat_A, $long_A, $lat_B, $long_B) {

      $distance = sin(deg2rad($lat_A))
          * sin(deg2rad($lat_B))
          + cos(deg2rad($lat_A))
          * cos(deg2rad($lat_B))
          * cos(deg2rad($long_A - $long_B));

      $distance = (rad2deg(acos($distance))) * 69.09;
      return $distance;


    }

    //if (isset ($_POST['submitted'])) {

      // Validate Zip code field
      if (!empty ($_POST['zipcode']) && is_numeric ($_POST['zipcode'])) {

        $z = (int)$_POST['zipcode'];
     //echo "zip=$z";
        // Verify zip code exists

        $query = "SELECT latitude, longitude FROM php_zip_code_distance WHERE postal= '$z'";
        $result = mysql_query ($query);

        if (mysql_num_rows ($result) == 1) {
          $zip = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result);
        } else {
          $Errors = '<p>The zip code you entered was not found!</p>';
          $z = NULL;
        }
     if (isset ($_POST['radius']) && is_numeric ($_POST['radius'])) {
        $r = (int)$_POST['radius'];
    //echo "r=$r";
      }


    $dbc = mysql_connect() or die (mysql_error

    ());
    mysql_select_db ();





    mysql_query("set sql_big_selects=1");
       //$stores = array();
        //$query = "SELECT catname, email, contact_name, zipcode, idnum,brief, name, title, latitude, longitude

      // INNER JOIN php_zip_code_distance
      // ON jml_aclsfgplt.zipcode = php_zip_code_distance.postal
    // WHERE $criteria";  
      //  $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);;

        // Go through and check all stores
       // while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {

          // Separate closest stores
     //     $distance = Dist ($row['latitude'], $row['longitude'], $zip['latitude'], $zip['longitude']);

          // Check if store is in radius
        //  if ($distance <= $r) {

          //  $stores[] = array (
    $query="select * from   where adphotos='yes'";
    $array = array();
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query\"$query\" Error:" . mysql_error()); 
    //$i=0;
    //while ($i < $num)

     //while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

       // 

      foreach (glob("/components/com_aclsfgpl/photos/*.{jpg,gif,png}",GLOB_BRACE) as $pathToThumb)
    {
    $start = '33';
    $end='-6';
    $counter = 0; 
        $filename = basename($pathToThumb);
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    //echo "2) ".basename($pathToThumb,'.'.$info['extension']);
    //echo "1) ".basename($pathToThumb, ".jpg").PHP_EOL;
        $pathToLarge = '/components/com_aclsfgpl/photos/'.$filename;
         //echo ("<div class='thumbnail'><a href='$pathToLarge'><img src='$pathToLarge' width='100' height = '100'/></a></div>");
    $substring= substr($pathToLarge, $start, $end)."<br />";

    $start2 = '11';
    $end2='-4';
    $substring2=substr($pathToLarge, $start2, $end2)."<br />";
    $arr2=array($substring2);
    //var_dump($arr2);
     //print $substring;
       //$arr=array($substring);
    $arr=array($substring);
    $arr1=array($filename);
    //echo "Intersect:$intersect"."<br />";

    //var_dump($arr);

    $counter++;

    $tempimage="( CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE images(
         image VARCHAR(10),
         substring VARCHAR(10) ))";  

    mysql_query($tempimage);  

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val1) {
    //echo "$key - <strong>$val</strong> <br />";
    //echo "$key - <strong>$val1</strong> <br />";
    $insert=" INSERT INTO images('image','substring')VALUES ($val,$val1)";
    mysql_query($insert); 

    $show_image= ("SELECT * FROM images");
    $result1=mysql_query($show_image);
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
    $image= $row['image'];
    $sub=$row['substring'];
    //echo $image;
    //echo $substring;




    }

    }}}

    $maketemp="create temporary table tmp_questions like  jml_aclsfgplt";
    mysql_query($maketemp) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());

    $minprice = $_POST['minPrice']  ;
      $maxprice =$_POST['MaxPrice'] ;

     $inserttemp = "INSERT INTO tmp_questions SELECT * FROM  WHERE price BETWEEN  $minprice AND  $maxprice "; 



    mysql_query($inserttemp) or die("Couldn't execute query\"$inserttemp\" Error:" . mysql_error());


    if(isset($_POST['categories']) && !empty($_POST['categories'])){ 
      foreach($_POST['categories'] as $key=>$value){ 
      if($value==1) $criteria_value[] = "$key"; 
        } 
        $criteria_value = implode(' || ', $criteria_value ); 
    } 


    //echo $criteria_value;
     $zipcode=(int)$_POST['zipcode'];
    //echo $zipcode;
     $radius=(int)$_POST['radius'];
     $minprice=$_POST['minPrice'];
     $maxprice=$_POST['MaxPrice'];
    //$mach1=$_POST['categories'];
    //$tstring = implode('||' ,$_POST['checklist']); 
    //$pieces = implode('||' ,$_POST['mach1']);
     //$search=$POST[search];
     $sql="INSERT INTO search (zipcode,distance,min,max,mach1,id,email,date) VALUES('$zipcode','$radius','$minprice','$maxprice','$criteria_value','$usr_id','$email_id',NOW())";
     mysql_query($sql);
    //}
    //$limit = (int)$_GET["price"];




    $query = "select * from tmp_questions  ";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query\"$query\" Error:" . mysql_error());  
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
       //echo "<div>".$row['title']."</div>";

    } 
    //echo $result;
     //$num=mysql_numrows($result);

    //echo "Num: $num";
    if(isset($_POST['categories']) && !empty($_POST['categories'])){ 
      foreach($_POST['categories'] as $key=>$value){ 
    if($value==1) $criteria[] = "`catname`='".mysql_escape_string($key)."'"; 
        } 
        $criteria = implode(' OR ', $criteria); 
    } 




    //$start = ($page-1)*$per_page;
    $sql_query1= "SELECT * FROM tmp_questions WHERE $criteria"; 
    $sql_res1=mysql_query("$sql_query1");
    //echo "minPrice:$minPrice";
    //echo "maxPrice:$MaxPrice";
    //while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_res1)){

    $array = array();
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(category) FROM Common");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $data=$row['category'];
    $data1=$row['value'];

    $array[] = $row['category'];

    echo $data1;
    //echo $data;
    }


    $sql_query1="select * from $table_ads  where idnum='$ITEM_NUM'";
    $sql_res1=mysql_query("$sql_query1");
    $row1 = mysql_fetch_array ($sql_res1);
    $price1=$row1['price']; 
    $mach1=$row1['mach1'];
    //echo "price:$price1";

    $pieces = explode("||", $mach1);

    $result1 = array_intersect($array,$pieces);

    foreach ($result1 as $key => $value) {
           //echo "<strong>$value</strong> <br />"; 

    $result3 = ("SELECT DISTINCT(value) FROM Common WHERE category IN ('$value')");

    $values=array_values($array);

    $result4=mysql_query("$result3");


        while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) != NULL)
    {

    $cat=$row['value'];

    //echo "<tr class=''>";



    //echo "<td>$cat</td>";

    $Image = $row["Images"];
    //echo $Image;
    $url="http://".$Image;

    }



    $maketemp1="create temporary table tmp_questions1 like   jml_aclsfgplt ";
    mysql_query($maketemp1) or die ("Sql error : ".mysql_error());


    $inserttemp = "INSERT INTO tmp_questions1 SELECT * FROM tmp_questions WHERE $criteria "; 

    mysql_query($inserttemp) or die("Couldn't execute query\"$inserttemp\" Error:" . mysql_error());

    mysql_query("set sql_big_selects=1");
       $stores = array();
        $query = "SELECT catname, price,email,adphotos,contact_name, zipcode, postal,idnum,brief, title, latitude, longitude
       FROM tmp_questions1
       INNER JOIN php_zip_code_distance
       ON tmp_questions1.zipcode = php_zip_code_distance.postal";
    //WHERE catname LIKE '%" . $_POST['category'] . "' ";  


        $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$query);;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){




    $distance = Dist ($row['latitude'], $row['longitude'], $zip['latitude'], $zip['longitude']);
    if ($distance <= $r) {
    $LAT=$row['latitude'];
    $LONG=$row['longitude'];
    $id_contactname=$row['contact_name']; 
    $CATNAME=$row['catname'];
    $PRICE=$row['price'];
    $TITLE=$row['title'];
    $zipcode=$row['zipcode'];
    $ITEM_NUM=$row['idnum'];
    $adphoto=$row['adphotos'];

    $details= "<a href='/index.php?option=com_aclsfgpl&Itemid=&ct1=&ct=&md=details&id=

    $ITEM_NUM'>Click for Item Details</a><br/>";

    if($adphoto =="yes")
     {

    $imagepath1= "p".$ITEM_NUM."n1.jpg";
    $path='/components/com_aclsfgpl/photos/'.$imagepath1;

    $image1=("<div class='thumbnail'><a href='$path'><img src='$path' width='100' height = '100' alt = 'No Images Posted' onerror='this.parentNode.removeChild(this)' /></a></div>");
    }
    else
    {
    $image1="Image is Pending";
    }

    //echo "<td>$val</td>";

    //$cats= "<a href='http://localhost/index.php?option=com_aclsfgpl&Itemid=$ITEM_NUM&ct1=&ct=&md=show_cat&id=
                        //      echo "<td>$LAT</td>";
                //echo "<td>$LONG</td>";
                //echo "<td>$CATNAME</td>";
                echo "<td>$$PRICE</td>";
     echo "<td>$TITLE</td>";
     echo "<td>$zipcode</td>";
     echo "<td>$ITEM_NUM</td>";
    echo "<td>$image1</td>";
     echo "<td>$details</td>";
     //echo "<td>$cont_email</td>";

                echo "</tr>";

          echo "<tr class=''>";

    }}
    $drop= "DROP table tmp_questions1";
    mysql_query("$drop");
   }




    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please format your question properly! And remove all the `X`...

Comment: I certainly will..thank you

Comment: Can anyone help on this one...Thank you

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.